# ta-lib gem not installing dependencies?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to run a simple example script from [here](https://github.com/mlamby/indicator), but even after installing requisite gems with no errors I get an error when running the script. It looks like `libta_lib.so` cant be found, but nothing in the install commands below had an error. Any idea what I am missing? Im happy to provide more data if needed, I just dont know what would be useful.

I ran:

```
#compiling ta-lib from source
gem uninstall talib_ruby
gem uninstall ta-indicator
make clean
sudo ./configure  LDFLAGS="-lm"
sudo make
sudo make install
gem install talib_ruby
gem install ta-indicator



king@death-star ~/Desktop/_REPOS/misc/stock_analysis/forex/oanda/ruby $ ruby -e "require 'talib_ruby'; l = TaLib::Function.new('MA') "
/home/king/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': libta_lib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/king/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/talib_ruby-1.0.6/lib/talib.so (LoadError)
    from /home/king/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/king/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/talib_ruby-1.0.6/lib/talib_ruby.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/king/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
    from /home/king/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/king/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you tell where files were installed to when you ran `make install`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this](https://ideaorchard.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/installing-ta-lib-ubuntu/) follow these steps

```
sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf
```

Append below line and save:

```
include /usr/local/lib

run sudo /sbin/ldconfig
```